# PHP | Сравнить два массива

Tags: php, массивы

Всем привет.

Как возможно сравнить два массива, в каждом из которых около 40 тысяч данных и если не нашло совпадения - вернуть мне ключи массивов, которые не нашлись.
Искать нужно по полю product_id
Пример массива(они оба идентичны) показано на картинке 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Для этого стоит писать цыкл или есть уже готовые варианты на PHP?

Comment: $result=array_diff($arr1,$arr2); print_r ($result); ps потренируйся вот на этом но допустим со 100 строками

Comment: но у меня около 40 000 данных. Как быть? Цыклом заполнять по 100 $arr1, $arr2? Как то не очень хорошо

Comment: я говорю попробуй как нибудь по 100 сделать массив, т.к сравнение больших делается в sql а не в php.

Comment: @Bloom вы не видите что у автора массив объектов, какие строки?

Comment: я не про строки а про array[0] array[1] итд до [100] т.к если их 40000 апатч не вытянет, да и если он учится то делается на sql

Comment: где у вас хранятся эти 40тыс. строк?

Comment: я беру данные из БД. По ответам выше я понял, что эту данную проверку нужно сделать на уровне SQL.

Comment: конешно да!!..вытягивайте данные по условию просто